# Getting error while deploying ASP.NET core application to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Below is the error,

```
    Application startup exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider.CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(String dependency)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider.CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(String dependency)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider.CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(String dependency)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider.CandidateResolver.<GetCandidates>d__4.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
       at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
       at LeapfrogDataService.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

My Program.cs looks like,

```
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

    namespace LeapfrogDataService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="args"></param>
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel()
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseIISIntegration()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build();

                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
```

And startup.cs looks like,

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

namespace LeapfrogDataService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
            {
                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="services"></param>
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Leapfrog API", Version = "v1" });
                var filePath = Path.Combine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "LeapfrogDataService.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
            });

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseMvc();

            var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddRedirectToHttps();

            app.UseRewriter(options);

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Leapfrog API V1");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this error?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1086

Comment: If you are using VSTS, I find a smilar [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/274416/keynotfoundexception.html?childToView=274417#comment-274417). Workaround is that  deploy the WebApp (to Azure) from VS2017 v15.7.3

Comment: @TomSunI followed mjwills GitHub thread and found a workaround there. I am not using VSTS but using GitHub. I believe both have a similar mechanism for deploying code to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is,

I added following lines in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` method.

```
// Configuring application part for MVC
var assembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var part = new AssemblyPart(assembly);
services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part));
```

And, also updated every single NuGet package associated with my project, don't know whether that really helps or not, but still, I did it.